# Lazy exception : size vs eager?

Tags: spring, jpa, lazy-loading

I was faced to a :

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ,no session or session was closed
```

When trying to access (from the controller, or a junit) the collection of "DataDictionaryEntry" that are in a "DataDictionary".

### DataDictionary

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "IDS_RAVE_DATA_DICTIONARY",
        uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"})
})
public class DataDictionary extends UnversionedObject {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dataDictionary",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<DataDictionaryEntry> dataDictionaryNames;

    /* constructor */
    public DataDictionary() {
        super();
    }


    /* getters & setters */
}
```

### DataDictionaryEntry

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "IDS_RAVE_DATA_DICTIONARY_ENTRY",
        uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"dataDictionary","codedData"})
})
public class DataDictionaryEntry extends UnversionedObject {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="dataDictionary")
    private DataDictionary dataDictionary;

    @Column
    private String codedData;

    @Column
    private Integer ordinal;

    @Column
    private String userDataString;

    @Column
    private Boolean specify;

    /* constructor */
    public DataDictionaryEntry() {
        super();
    }

    /* getters & setters */
}
```

I do have an abstract service object and another service extending it :

### Generic service

```
@Transactional
public abstract class RaveGeneralServiceImpl<T> implements RaveGeneralService<T> {

    private JpaRepository<T, Long> repo;

    /**
     * Init the general rave services with your specific repo
     * @param repo
     */
    protected void init(JpaRepository<T, Long> repo){
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(){
         return repo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T obj){
         return repo.save(obj);
     }

    @Override
    public void flush(){
        repo.flush();
    }

}
```

### DataDictionaryServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class DataDictionaryServiceImpl extends RaveGeneralServiceImpl<DataDictionary> implements DataDictionaryService {
    @Resource
    private DataDictionaryRepository dataDictionaryRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.init(dataDictionaryRepository);
    }

}
```

I could find replies on how to solve it. The first solution often seen is to change to LAZY to a EAGER. When I printed the generated query when accessing a FINDALL() method it shows the following :

```
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        DataDictionary as generatedAlias0 */ select
            datadictio0_.ID as ID81_,
            datadictio0_.createdByUser as createdB2_81_,
            datadictio0_.createdTime as createdT3_81_,
            datadictio0_.lastUpdateTime as lastUpda4_81_,
            datadictio0_.lastUpdateUser as lastUpda5_81_,
            datadictio0_.VERSION as VERSION81_,
            datadictio0_.name as name81_ 
        from
            IDS_RAVE_DATA_DICTIONARY datadictio0_
Hibernate: 
    /* load one-to-many com.bdls.ids.model.rave.DataDictionary.dataDictionaryNames */ select
        datadictio0_.dataDictionary as dataDic11_81_1_,
        datadictio0_.ID as ID1_,
        datadictio0_.ID as ID82_0_,
        datadictio0_.createdByUser as createdB2_82_0_,
        datadictio0_.createdTime as createdT3_82_0_,
        datadictio0_.lastUpdateTime as lastUpda4_82_0_,
        datadictio0_.lastUpdateUser as lastUpda5_82_0_,
        datadictio0_.VERSION as VERSION82_0_,
        datadictio0_.codedData as codedData82_0_,
        datadictio0_.dataDictionary as dataDic11_82_0_,
        datadictio0_.ordinal as ordinal82_0_,
        datadictio0_.specify as specify82_0_,
        datadictio0_.userDataString as userDat10_82_0_ 
    from
        IDS_RAVE_DATA_DICTIONARY_ENTRY datadictio0_ 
    where
        datadictio0_.dataDictionary=?
```

The 2nd solution we often see is to make a call to the .size() of the component that is being lazily initialized. So indeed by changing my service to this :

```
@Service
public class DataDictionaryServiceImpl extends RaveGeneralServiceImpl<DataDictionary> implements DataDictionaryService {
    @Resource
    private DataDictionaryRepository dataDictionaryRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.init(dataDictionaryRepository);
    }

    @Override
    public List<DataDictionary> findAll() {
        List<DataDictionary> results = super.findAll();
        for (DataDictionary dd : results) {
            dd.getDataDictionaryNames().size();// init lazy
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

The lazy exception is also gone ! But the end result is the same query... So the what is the added value of keeping it LAZY if the end-query is the same ? Or did I do it wrong ?

Suppose that for the front-end you would have a data table that displays only basic information (the name for example), it would call the findAll() but still query the complete dependencies of that object ?

Comment: When you mark the relationship as EAGER, add: @Fetch(SELECT) annotation too (it's a hibernate annotation). You can change query this way. You can change the SELECT option to SUBSELECT and see the results.

Answer (score 1):

While the results with this method are pretty much exactly the same, the value of keeping it lazy is that if you don't need it fetched in other queries, you don't automatically have it eagerly fetched.  Making the relationship eager applies to every method of accessing that entity, while calling size on a collection forces it to be fetched for that one occurrence.

There are other ways that might be more efficient, such as using a join fetch qualifier in the JPA query itself, allowing the provider to fetch the relationship using a single select.

Comment: Thanks Chris, and suppose that for the front-end you would have a data table that displays only basic information (the name for example), it would call the findAll() but still query the complete dependencies of that object ? Ideally I was seeing LAZY to retrieve the dependencies only when there is a call to the getter of that dependency ?

Comment: Lazy means the provider can fetch the data only if it is needed.  So if you don't touch it on the entity, it will not be fetched from the database - the provider will read in only the eager data required to build the entity.  This is what you say you are seeing - the find all will fetch only eager mappings and relationships, while the lazy relationships are only retrieved when a get or set method is called.  You mark relationships that you do not always use as lazy to avoid the cost of always fetching them from the database when they are not always needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use: Hibernate.initialize() to initialize Lazy collections.

Or using spring to avoid LazyException use filer in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But remember, using lazy fetching is bad idea if you are thinking about good application design and performance.